# jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog

I am trying to open a dialog window `onclick` for each link with the class specified below. But it's not working.  However, the code works if I replace `.dialog('open');` with `.hide();`

I don't understand why it's not working if I can attach the click event with `hide()` but not dialog.

Any suggestions are welcome. :) ty

```
$('.btn_readbio').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){ 
        $(this).dialog('open'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.. but do you need to init the dialog with $('.btn_readbio').dialog(); before .dialog('open') will work? haven't played with it myself...

Comment: init it outside the click handler...

Answer (score 1):

This code is working:

```
$('.btn_readbio').click(function(){ 
     $(this).dialog(); 
});
```

I removed the 'open' parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code after adding the dialogs container to the 'rel' attribute of the hyperlink:

```
$('.btn_readbio').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){ $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).dialog('open'); });
});
```